# there is a way to optimize this mysql query?

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

```
SELECT T1.name AS hotel, 
       T2.name AS city 
  FROM (SELECT * 
          FROM hotel 
         WHERE name LIKE '$term1%') T1,
       (SELECT * 
          FROM city 
         WHERE name LIKE '$term2%') T2
 WHERE T1.city_id = T2.id
```

T1 have 150000, T2 have 15000. (static tables!)
i have indexes on 'name' for this tables.

there is a way to optimize this mysql query?
i also want to do -> LIKE '%term1%' but its very very slow.

Comment: And then they invented the concept of [joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). Which was nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First step is to re-write the query using ANSI-92 [JOIN syntax](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html):

```
SELECT h.name AS hotel,
       c.name AS city
  FROM HOTEL h
  JOIN CITY c ON c.id = h.city_id
 WHERE h.name LIKE '$term1%'
   AND c.name LIKE '$term2%'
```

After that, look at indexing:

- HOTEL.name
- HOTEL.city_id
- CITY.name
- CITY.id

...in a variety of combinations.

Comment: its exectly what i did, my query is JOIN. but i have seperated indexes. i mean index for each column, what you mean by saing ".in a variety of combinations."?

Comment: i added the 3 other indexes to each of the 4 indexes. and now its extremely improved! thanks alot!

Comment: @Ben: An index can be for a single column, but most databases support composite indexes which can contain more than one column.  But there's a catch to composite indexes - the order of the columns matters, and they are processed from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just join directly between hotel and city and move the two LIKE statements to the WHERE clause.

If you can change the table structure and if there is a lot of duplication of names you could normalize name to a key and search a smaller table for the key that matches the name and then lookup the data based on the name's key.

Also add indexes based on "OMG Ponies" answer.

Answer (score 0):

one way to improve the performance is to put a fulltext index on the name columns of those tables.

Comment: Caveat is that MySQL requires tables to be MyISAM if using MySQL Full Text Search.

Answer (score 0):

> i also want to do -> LIKE '%term1%' but its very very slow

Maybe `name LIKE '$term%' OR reverse_name LIKE '$reverse_term%'` is faster than `name LIKE '%$term%'`. With appropriate indizes of course.

I never tried ... just popped into my head.

Comment: OR's are notoriously bad performers.  Wildcarding the left side of a `LIKE` ensures that an index on the column can not be used.

Comment: there is a way to do it faster? because %term% takes couple of seconds to perform.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: That's why I suggest not to wildcard the left but the right side (of the reversed string).